# Setting tab background in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, tabs

i'm making an android application, and i have a tabhost and two tabs in my xml. I have called them and they work just fine. But i want to get rid of the ugly grey/orange color on tabs. I have tried setting the bg using an image. I used this code:

```
th.getTabWidget().setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_normal);
```

But it shows up like this:

[image: Wrong bg]

How can i get it to replace the gray and orange color?

Thanks

Comment: You're in for a treat. I can not prepare you for the hell you are going into, that's how horrible tabs is on android. The style is different for each manufacturer and for each version of android. That is also why the old tabs now are deprecated... and you should start using the new ones by using actionbarsherlock or similar. Oh also I forgot some of the features can't be styled on some version of android unless you do some risky code that might break :S

Comment: Ok, thanks :P I'm also using ABS (action bar sherlock) in my app. But i want the tabs to only be from the mid and down. And not take the full layout. Thanks again.

Comment: What do you mean with only from mid and down?

Comment: having a image over the tabs, so it would be

Image
Tab1 | Tab2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps to fully customize tabwidget:

1. Create custom layout for tabwidget: this layout similar to default one which consist of one `Icon` and one `TextView`. You can choose whatever layout you want. Notice that the parent layout has stateful background `tabwidget_selector`. This drawable is the key to replace default orange focus color. You can choose your own focus color.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="40dp"
   android:background="@drawable/tabwidget_selector"
   android:gravity="center"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/tabIndicatorIcon"
       android:layout_width="28dp"
       android:layout_height="28dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="2dp" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/tabIndicatorText"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
       android:textColor="@color/white" />
   ```
2. Write function which return a view for `tabwidget`. Set text, icon drawable for your tabwidget

   ```
   private View getTabIndicatorView(Context context, String tag, int drawable) {
       View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
               R.layout.tab_widget_custom, null);
       TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tabIndicatorText);
       tv.setText(tag);
       ImageView tabIndicatorIcon = (ImageView) view
               .findViewById(R.id.tabIndicatorIcon);
       tabIndicatorIcon.setBackgroundResource(drawable);
       return view;

   }
   ```
3. Use this function in your activity:

> TabHost.TabSpec   setIndicator(View view) Specify a view as the tab
>   indicator.

```
       Intent intent;
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;

        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Inbox").setIndicator(
                getTabIndicatorView(MainTabActivity.this, "Hộp thư",
                        R.drawable.tin_nhan_tab_selector));
        intent = new Intent(this, xxxx.InboxActivity.class);

        spec.setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have background for tabwidget:

```
   <TabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">

        <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/tabbackground"
        android:layout_margin="7dp"

        />


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_above="@android:id/tabs" 
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
            android:layout_margin="5dp" 
            android:background="@drawable/list_shape">
         </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```